# Launching MS Office from WPF application

Tags: c#, process, outlook, ms-word, ms-office

As part of an application, I've added a shortcut bar for relevantly used programs.  I have it set up to check if the application is open already, and if it is to switch to it instead of opening another instance.  This works fine for programs like calc and notepad, but all the MS Office programs open another instance no matter what, and I'd like them not to.

**Office Button**

```
    private void wordButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            SwitchToProcess("winword.exe", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\winword.exe");
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                SwitchToProcess("winword.exe", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\winword.exe");
            }
            catch (Win32Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

**Notepad Button**

```
    private void notepadLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SwitchToProcess("notepad.exe");
    }
```

**Methods**

```
private void SwitchToProcess(string name)
    {
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
        if (procs.Length != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (procs[i].MainModule.ModuleName == name)
                    {
                        IntPtr hwnd = procs[i].MainWindowHandle;
                        ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
                        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No process running");
            return;
        }
        launchApp.StartInfo.FileName = name;
        launchApp.Start();
    }

    private void SwitchToProcess(string name, string path)
    {
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcesses();
        if (procs.Length != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (procs[i].MainModule.ModuleName == name)
                    {
                        IntPtr hwnd = procs[i].MainWindowHandle;
                        ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
                        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No process running");
            return;
        }
        launchApp.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        launchApp.Start();
    }
```

The reason for the two different directories in the Office button is a simple way of ensuring that x86/x64 install locations don't cause a problem.  The computers I'm developing this for have the registry locked out, so I can't check which one is correct.

Comment: And what if office is installed on some other drive?

Comment: I plan at some point on adding a section in the setting tab to customize file locations, etc.  For now thought this simplifies it 'til I get it working completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after digging a little deeper into Google, I finally figured out the problem.  I had the program targeted for an x86 processor, and am running it on x64.  Switched the target to AnyCPU and it works perfectly.  Apparently it was catching an error of `Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed`, but since I had the try-catch block in there it wasn't displaying the error until I used StepInto repeatedly on the 77-item processor array.  Thanks everyone for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

In your `SwitchToProcess` method you need to change the following line:

```
if (procs[i].MainModule.ModuleName == name)
```

To this:

```
if (procs[i].MainModule.ModuleName.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
```

Reason being that the process name for Word is WINWORD.EXE and you are passing the parameter value in lowercase.

As an aside you could change your `wordButton_Click` event to this:

```
private void wordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                SwitchToProcess("winword.exe", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\winword.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                SwitchToProcess("winword.exe", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\winword.exe");
            }
}
```

Comment: I had tried having it both upper and lower cased before I posted this, and it didn't work.  I did add the ToLower() though and tried it again, but it still doesn't work.  Either way I like having the ToLower in there, as it will avoid potential problems if any other programs are upper or lower.  As for the Environment suggestion, I would use that except that the computers that will use it are 64-bit, they just installed it to the x86 folder for some reason.

Comment: It might be worth checking the Task Manager and seeing what the image name is for WINWORD.EXE, I think it will possibly be WINWORD.EXE*32 you need to look for - I'm assuming the Office install is 32bit on the 64bit machines?